# supposed infinite loop - cleart.contnts run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, infinite-loop

As an everlasting VBA newbe, I am here again to ask for your help.
I wrote this code:

```
Public ANNO As String

Sub FIFO_new()
Worksheets(15).Select
Call FifoCanc
Dim fifodest As Worksheet, fifosource As Worksheet
Dim ColumnA As Variant, ColumnB As Variant, ColumnE As Variant, ColumnF As Variant, ColumnL As Variant
Dim ColumnR As Variant, ColumnS As Variant, ColumnQ As Variant, ColumnU As Variant, ColumnT As Variant
Dim E As Integer, F As Integer
INIZIO:

'-----------------------------------------------
Set fifodest = Worksheets(15)
F = fifodest.Range("M2").Value
'------------------------------------------------
'AGGIUNGI/TOGLI RIGHE A FOGLIO VUOTO
If F = 0 Or F = -1 Then
    D = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    D = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
D = D - 1
With Range("A3:A" & D)
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
With Range("E3:E" & D)
.NumberFormat = "##,###,##0.00 ""KG"""
End With
With Range("F3:F" & D)
.NumberFormat = "##,##0.00 ""€/KG"""
End With
With Range("G3:G" & D)
.NumberFormat = "€ #,##0.00"
End With

If D < 14 And (F = 0 Or F = -1) Then
    MsgBox ("RIGHE INSUFFICIENTI")
    Range("A" & (F + 3)).Select
    H = ActiveCell.Row
    Do Until D = 15
        If F = 0 Or F = -1 Then
            F = 4
        End If
        Range("A" & F & ":L" & F).Select
        Range("A" & F & ":L" & F).Insert shift:=xlDown
        If F = 0 Or F = -1 Then
            D = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
        Else
            D = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
        End If
    Loop
ElseIf D > 15 And (F = 0 Or F = -1) Then
'    D = Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    K = (D - 15)
    If F = 0 Or F = -1 Then
        F = 3
    End If
    Range("A" & F & ":L" & (F + K)).Delete shift:=xlUp
End If
'------------------------------------------------

li:
C = InputBox("INIZIO INTERVALLO (DA 1 A 12)")
D = InputBox("FINE INTERVALLO (DA 1 A 12)")
C = C + 1
D = D + 1
If D - C < 0 Then
    MsgBox ("iniziale sempre < di finale")
    GoTo li
End If

For I = C To D
Set fifosource = Worksheets(I)
E = fifosource.Range("V6").Value
If E = 0 Then
    GoTo vainext
End If
Set ColumnR = fifosource.Range("R7:R" & (E + 6))
Set ColumnS = fifosource.Range("S7:S" & (E + 6))
Set ColumnQ = fifosource.Range("Q7:Q" & (E + 6))
Set ColumnU = fifosource.Range("U7:U" & (E + 6))
Set ColumnT = fifosource.Range("T7:T" & (E + 6))

'AGGIUNGI RIGHE---------------------------------------
F = fifodest.Range("M2").Value
If F = 0 Or F = -1 Then
    L = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    L = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
L = L - 1
    If L < 14 Then
        GoTo INIZIO
        I = Nothing
    ElseIf L < (14 + (E + (F + 1))) Then
            If F = 0 Or F = -1 Then
                M = 4
            Else
                M = F + 3
            End If
            Range("A" & M & ":L" & (M + (E - 1))).Insert shift:=xlDown
'            D = Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
'------------------------------------------------------

If F = 0 Or F = -1 Then
    M = 3
End If
Set ColumnA = fifodest.Range("A" & M & ":A" & (E + (M - 1)))
ColumnA.Select
ColumnA.Value = ColumnR.Value
Set ColumnB = fifodest.Range("B" & M & ":B" & (E + (M - 1)))
ColumnB.Value = ColumnS.Value
Set ColumnE = fifodest.Range("E" & M & ":E" & (E + (M - 1)))
ColumnE.Value = ColumnQ.Value
Set ColumnF = fifodest.Range("F" & M & ":F" & (E + (M - 1)))
ColumnF.Value = ColumnU.Value
Set ColumnL = fifodest.Range("L" & M & ":L" & (E + (M - 1)))
ColumnL.Value = ColumnT.Value
Call Gformula
vainext:
Next
fifodest.Select

Set fifodest = ActiveSheet '------

F = fifodest.Range("M2").Value
If F <= 0 Then
    L = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    L = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
L = L - 1

'elimina righe in eccesso
If F > 0 And L - F > 7 Then
K = (L - (F + 2)) - 7
Range("A" & (F + 4) & ":L" & (F + 2 + K)).Delete shift:=xlUp
End If

'calcolo valori ultima riga
F = fifodest.Range("M2").Value
If F <= 0 Then
    L = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    L = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If

''L = L + 1
Range("A" & L).ClearContents
Range("A" & L).Value = Range("A" & (F + 2)).Value
Range("A" & L).Font.Bold = True

UserForm1.Show

For Each cell In Range("A3:A" & L)
If cell.Value <> "" Then
    cell.Value = Left(cell, 6) & ANNO 'Right(cell, 4) = ANNO
End If
Next

With Range("A3:A" & L)
.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

With Range("H3:K" & L)
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End With

With Range("D" & L)
.ClearContents
.Value = "Totali"
.Font.Bold = True
End With

With Range("E" & L)
.ClearContents
.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E3:E" & (L - 1)).Value)
.Font.Bold = True
.NumberFormat = "##,###,##0.00 ""KG"""
End With

With Range("G" & L)
.ClearContents
.Formula = "=SUM(G3:G" & (L - 1) & ")"
.Font.Bold = True
.NumberFormat = "€ #,##0.00"
End With

With Range("L" & L)
.ClearContents
.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L3:L" & (L - 1)).Value)
.Font.Bold = True
End With

Call WidthColonna
B = 0
For I = C To D
A = Worksheets(I).Range("V6").Value
B = A + B
Next
F = Range("M2").Value
If B <> F Then
    Range("M2").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
    Range("M2").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="ponzio"
End Sub


Sub Gformula()
Dim cella As Range, cella2 As Range
B = Range("M2").Value + 1
If F <= 0 Then
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
A = A - 1

Set cella = Range("G3")
    cella.Select
    If cella.FormulaArray <> "" And cella.Row = 3 Then
        GoTo dopo
    End If
    cella.ClearContents
    cella.FormulaArray = "=IF(RC5>=0,RC[-2]*RC[-1],-(MAX(IF(R2C8:RC8<-SUMIF(R2C5:RC5,""<0""),R2C9:RC9))-(SUMIF(R2C5:RC5,""<0"")+MAX(IF(R2C8:RC8<-SUMIF(R2C5:RC5,""<0""),R2C8:RC8)))*INDEX(R2C6:RC6,MATCH(MIN(IF(R2C8:RC8>=-SUMIF(R2C5:RC5,""<0""),R2C8:RC8)),R2C8:RC8,0))+1111))"
    cella.Replace "1111", "SUMIF(OFFSET(G3,-1,0,-ROW(G3)+1,1),""<0"")"
dopo:
Range("G4:G" & A).ClearContents
If B = 1 Then
   GoTo qui
End If
Range("G3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G3:G" & (B + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
qui:
Set cella2 = Range("G3:G" & A)
'    For Each cell In cella2
'        If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(cell) = True Then
'            cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -5).Value * (cell.Offset(-1, -3).Value / cell.Offset(-1, -5).Value)
'        End If
'    Next


Call Dformula
End Sub

Sub Dformula()
Dim cella As Range, cella2 As Range
B = Range("M2").Value + 1
If F <= 0 Then
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
A = A - 1
Set cella = Range("D3")
    cella.Select
    If cella.FormulaArray <> "" And cella.Row = 3 Then
        GoTo dopo
    End If
    cella.ClearContents
    cella.FormulaArray = "=IF(E3>0,""Entrata"",IF(E3<0,""Uscita"",""-""))"

dopo:
Range("D4:D" & A).ClearContents
If B = 1 Then
   GoTo qui
End If
Range("D3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:D" & (B + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
qui:
Call Hformula
End Sub

Sub Hformula()
Dim cella As Range, cella2 As Range
B = Range("M2").Value + 1
If F <= 0 Then
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
A = A - 1
Set cella = Range("H3")
    cella.Select
    If cella.FormulaArray <> "" And cella.Row = 3 Then
        GoTo dopo
    End If
    cella.ClearContents
    cella.FormulaArray = "=SUMIF($E$3:$E3,"">0"")"
dopo:
Range("H4:H" & A).ClearContents
If B = 1 Then
   GoTo qui
End If
Range("H3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H3:H" & (B + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
qui:
Call Iformula
End Sub

Sub Iformula()
Dim cella As Range, cella2 As Range
B = Range("M2").Value + 1
If F <= 0 Then
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
A = A - 1
Set cella = Range("I3")
    cella.Select
    If cella.FormulaArray <> "" And cella.Row = 3 Then
        GoTo dopo
    End If
    cella.ClearContents
    cella.FormulaArray = "=SUMIF($E$3:$E3,"">0"",$G$3:$G3)"
dopo:
Range("I4:I" & A).ClearContents
If B = 1 Then
   GoTo qui
End If
Range("I3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I3:I" & (B + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
qui:
Call Jformula
End Sub

Sub Jformula()
Dim cella As Range, cella2 As Range
B = Range("M2").Value + 1
If F <= 0 Then
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
A = A - 1
Set cella = Range("J3")
    cella.Select
    If cella.FormulaArray <> "" And cella.Row = 3 Then
        GoTo dopo
    End If
    cella.ClearContents
    cella.FormulaArray = "=IF(ROW(RC10)=3,RC5,R[-1]C10+RC5)"
dopo:
Range("J4:J" & A).ClearContents
If B = 1 Then
   GoTo qui
End If
Range("J3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:J" & (B + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
qui:
Call Kformula
End Sub
Sub Kformula()
Dim cella As Range, cella2 As Range
B = Range("M2").Value + 1
If F <= 0 Then
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    A = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
End If
A = A - 1
Set cella = Range("K3")
    cella.Select
    If cella.FormulaArray <> "" And cella.Row = 3 Then
        GoTo dopo
    End If
    cella.ClearContents
    cella.FormulaArray = "=IF(ROW(RC11)=3,RC7,R[-1]C11+RC7)"
dopo:
Range("K4:K" & A).ClearContents
If B = 1 Then
   GoTo qui
End If
Range("K3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K3:K" & (B + 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
qui:
End Sub

Sub WidthColonna()
With Worksheets(15)
.ColumnS(5).ColumnWidth = 15
.ColumnS(7).ColumnWidth = 12
.ColumnS(8).ColumnWidth = 12
.ColumnS(9).ColumnWidth = 12
.ColumnS(10).ColumnWidth = 12
.ColumnS(11).ColumnWidth = 12
.ColumnS(12).ColumnWidth = 8
End With
H = Range("M2").Value
If H > 4990 Then
    MsgBox ("ATTENZIONE: LINEE RECORDS > 5000")
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Sub FifoCanc()
Worksheets(15).Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="ponzio"
F = Range("m2").Value

If F > 0 Then
    D = Range("D3").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row - 1
ElseIf F = -1 Or F = 0 Then
    D = Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row - 1
End If
G = InputBox("CANCELLO TUTTO? (S/N)")
G = UCase(G)
If G = "S" Then
    Range("A3:L" & D).ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

When it calls the `fifocan` subroutine, in the line where clear contents is required, it's stuck and returns

> run time error 1004 clear contents method of range class failed.

The same thing happens in the other called sub routines:

- Gformula
- Hformula etc.

when it reaches the line with `range.clear contents` it's stuck.
There is surely an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: Describe "it's stuck" more precisely - what, exactly, happens? Also you should post s *minimal* code example to repro the problem [mcve] - this is much too much code to have to wade through... And you should fix the indenting to at least make it easier to read.

Comment: ^^Shorten to minimal example and indicate the exact line where the error occurs.  Use explicit worksheet references. Be careful with sheet index in case sheet order changes. Use Option Explicit at the top of your code. Use Long rather than Integer to avoid overflow. And be careful with all those GoTos.   i = Nothing is not valid for i as numeric use 0. Declare all your variables. Lose the obsolete CALL word. Avoid .Select and use With statements. And use <> vbNullString rather than <> ""

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try all your tip. Just to be more precise, when i run the code by pressing,f8, everything seems working fine but if i launch it by pressing green triangle button, it returns error and excel workbook breakdown. I need to open up task manager utulity by ppressing ctrl+alt+canc and manually force to close down excel task loosing all data i insert before in meantime

Comment: 1004 can easily happen when range refers to a 0 or negative row value. Check the values before `.Clear`. And use `Option Explicit`. It is worth.

Comment: hi guys thanks for all your support but the problem lies in here:                    https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/23956-clearcontents-problem-solved-2.html?s=1a4e7f58b9ae2c5c8ff02ae65935f66b                another excel puzzler.::::::::OOOOOO    the worksheets was simply corrupted hten i delete and moved everything to a new one. that's it

Comment: Hi.last solution was not working properly. The right one is to add this command in the beginning of the procedure: application.screenupdate=false. I hope it may help other user